# Voting without account

Tags: php, database, html, css

We want to create a website.
In this website, we want people to vote for a "like" like on facebook, but without accounts.
Is there any solutions to make that people can only vote once (like check IP & name of the browser, ...) ?

Comment: Do Google this, there are many voting scripts out there, you don't need us.

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's easy.

I would do a combination of saving the IP Address as well as putting a cookie on a computer.

Won't help against people using tor and anonymous browser, but basically it's the best way to do it, as it will keep 99.9% of people from voting again.

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = -> ip address of user

setcookie("alreadyVoted", "1", time()+3600*24);  /* expire in 24 hours so person can vote again set higher if you don't want that */
```

Comment: what happens if the user reboots his router? what if different people with the same ip want to vote?

Comment: Will not keep those from wanting to manipulate the voting to double vote. There are attempts to make cookies "virtually irrevokable", but their use is subject to discussion (possibility of identification; right for privacy ...): [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/).

Comment: Adding onto this, instead of using a cookie, you could store their IP in a database so even if they clear their cookies, you still control their ability to vote.

Comment: and what if the user decide not to stock or to clean the cookie ?

Comment: as the others said - there won't be a 100% ideal solution unless you let people register, use a captcha & e-mail validation. if you don't do this, if someone really knows what he/she is doing he can and will be able to double vote.

edit - and even then someone will still be able to double vote if he puts in the effort. but there are lots of voting scripts out there (google php voting script) - however what you want to accomplish won't be possible without registration. you can have either or. depending on the purpose you can choose one or the other method.

Answer (score -1):

It will never be 100% reliable, but [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) gets close.